# Migrating Alamofire.Request extension from Swift 2 to Swift 3

Tags: swift3, swift2, alamofire

I'm trying to migrate an extension to Alamofire.Request but am getting the error `Cannot call value of non-function type 'HTTPURLResponse?'`.

I know the compiler thinks I'm referring to the member response and not the function.

I've already replaced Request.JSONResponseSerializer with DataRequest.jsonResponseSerializer.

Can anyone see what I'm missing?

```
extension Alamofire.Request {
    public func responseSwiftyJSON(_ queue: DispatchQueue? = nil, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions = .allowFragments, completionHandler:  @escaping (NSURLRequest, HTTPURLResponse?, SwiftyJSON.JSON, Error?) -> Void) -> Self {
        return response(responseSerializer: Alamofire.DataRequest.jsonResponseSerializer(options: options)) { response in
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
                var responseJSON: JSON

                if response.result.isFailure {
                    responseJSON = JSON.null
                } else {
                    responseJSON = SwiftyJSON.JSON(response.result.value!)
                }

                dispatch_async(queue ?? dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    completionHandler(self.request!, self.response, responseJSON, response.result.error)
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is compatible with older versions, but I suggest you rewrite your extensions as this:

```
extension DataRequest {
    public func responseSwiftyJSON(queue: DispatchQueue? = nil, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions = .allowFragments, completionHandler:  @escaping (URLRequest?, HTTPURLResponse?, SwiftyJSON.JSON, Error?) -> Void) -> Self {
        return responseJSON(queue: queue, options: options) {
            let responseJSON: JSON
            switch result {
            case let .success(json): responseJSON = JSON(json)
            case .failure: responseJSON = JSON.null
            }

            completionHandler(request, response, responseJSON, error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks! I didn't realize the functionality had been moved to DataRequest, no wonder it didn't work.